# Show inequality and find conditions turning to equality

Tags: inequality

Given set of numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n; a_i \geq 0 \; \forall i = 1, ..., n$, the largest of this numbers is denoted as $a > 0$.

I need to show that $\dfrac{a_1^2 + ... + a_n^2}{n} \leq \Big(\dfrac{a_1 + ... + a_n}{n} \Big)^2 + \dfrac{a^2}{4} $ and answer when inequality turns to equality.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\frac{a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2}{n}-\left(\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n}\right)^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\sum\limits_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)^2\right)$.

Comment: @Juicer I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.